# Remove ionCube from CentOS server

Tags: centos, php, webserver, extension, zend

Someone in our workplace encrypted some files with ionCube in our main code repository, I can't find any file related on how to remove this extension/module or whatever it is when I look to our PHP info file. Is there any way to remove this and have our files back to normal? The operating system is CentOS 7.

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
> with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v5.0.19, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.